# OpenSSL on µITRON

Tags: openssl, arm, embedded, itron

I'm thinking about using OpenSSL for my embedded products which implements an ARM processor and µITRON kernel. I couldn't find the use-case that uses OpenSSL with µITRON. Is there any useful document to port OpenSSL on µITRON environment?

Comment: I would suggest a more appropriate alternative:  https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2020-February/011851.html

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, [µITRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRON_project) is not a kernel or RTOS itself, but rather a specification for an RTOS API. You should perhaps look for an SSL solution for your specific implementation, it is not really specific to the µITRON API.  There are other commercial SSL implementations that can be used with µITRON.